# The report definition is not valid. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> The report definition is not valid. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

I am using ASP.NET MVC framework. To error comes when I `setparameter()` call to set the data into rdlc designing report.

`viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("SaleDataSet", modelList));` This line of code executed successfully,and report has been printed.

But at below line,
`viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(parms);`
error comes.

An error comes during local report processing.
The report definition has an invalid target namespace.

```
public ActionResult PrintSaleReport(string saleId)
{
    try
    {
        Decimal sId = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(saleId))
        {
            sId = Convert.ToDecimal(saleId);
        }

        var saleList = new SaleRepository().GetById(sId);
        List<SalesModel> modelList = new List<SalesModel>();
        foreach (var item in saleList.SaleHistories)
        {

            SalesModel obj = new SalesModel();
            obj.StockName = item.Stock.Name;
            obj.saleQuantity = item.Quantity + "";
            obj.SaleHistoryPrice = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(item.SalePrice), 2) + "";
            obj.Expr = Convert.ToDecimal(obj.saleQuantity) * Convert.ToDecimal(obj.SaleHistoryPrice) + "";
            modelList.Add(obj);
        }
        var TotalAmount = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(saleList.TotalBill), 2);
        var discount = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(saleList.Discount), 2);
        var invoiceNumber = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm tt");
        var itemCount = saleList.SaleHistories.Count();

        ReportParameter[] parms = new ReportParameter[1];
        parms[0] = new ReportParameter("[TotalAmount]", TotalAmount + "");
        //parms[1] = new ReportParameter("[Discount]", discount+"");
        //parms[2] = new ReportParameter("[InvoiceId]", invoiceNumber + "");
        //parms[3] = new ReportParameter("itemCount", itemCount + "");

        var viewer = new ReportViewer();

        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "SaleReport.rdlc");
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = path;

        }
        else
        {
            return View("Index");
        }

        viewer.LocalReport.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("SaleDataSet", modelList));
        viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(parms);
        string reportType = "PDF";
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        byte[] renderedBytes;
        //string deviceInfo =
        //    "<DeviceInfo>" +
        //   "<OutputFormat>" + "PDF" + "</OutputFormat>" +
        //   "<PageWidth> 8.5in</PageWidth>" +
        //   "<PageHeight> 11in</PageHeight>" +
        //   "<MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
        //   "<MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" +
        //   "<MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
        //   "<MarginBottom>1in</MarginBottom>" +
        //  "</DeviceInfo>";
        renderedBytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render(
            reportType,
            null,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings
             );
        return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string message = ex.Message;
        string innermesasge = ex.InnerException.Message;
        var moreinnerMsg = ex.InnerException.InnerException;
        throw ex;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you using RDL or RDLC report? I think you can set the report XML header to version 2010, can you provide report XML code which has problem then?

Comment: I am using rdlc report, on visual studio 2017.Exception is created when 
 viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(parms);
calls.
The report definition has an invalid target namespace.

Comment: You can try update `ReportViewer` assemblies to version 14.0.0.0, then install `Microsoft.RdlcDesigner` (it is possible that VS automatically changed existing RDLC namespaces to current report version you're using).

Comment: Thanks.its worked for me.Issue is resolved succcessfully.

Answer (score 4):

Many have answered various permutations of this question by telling people to edit headers of old RDLC reports. This is a horrible idea. Generally, this issue materializes because you are using an version of the `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms` dll that is not compatible with the Sql Server/ Sql server lite that you are trying to run the report due to:

1. Upgrading versions of visual studio and are using the newer report template with the older .dll
2. Pulling code from a repository that was developed by someone using an older version of the .dll and you are editing it in a newer version of visual studio

The solution is to upgrade the version of the .dll  through nuget. Visual Studio 2017 requires version 140.xxx.xx (which is compatible with Sql Server 2016 and previous versions). Look for `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.140.340.80`

Answer (score 0):

These two options have worked for me:

1. Exclude the report from the project. then include it back
2. Recreate the report, copy its design code and save

I started seeing some hidden errors in design which were not coming up, I guess because I am dealing with a very large project, so some errors may take time before they come up (VS2010)