# error with RDLC in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, rdlc

The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First off, you didn't ask a question - but since you're new here and I recognize this error, I'll point you to  previous answer I gave that I think will help: [Check this post out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46543203/the-report-definition-is-not-valid-details-the-report-definition-has-an-invali/49409208#49409208)